# How to connect guest Ubuntu 12.10 server in Hyper-V to my network on the host machine?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, networking, switch, hyper-v

I'm using Windows 8 Pro with Hyper-V 6.2
I successfully installed Ubuntu 12.10 server into the Hyper-V, but until now way I'm not able to connect it to my network. I created internal and external virtual switch, both pointing to the the physical adapter on the host machine, and nothing.

Maybe there is some step I didn't do, or software i need to install.

Hope some of you can give me a hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using the Hyper-V management console to manage your virtual machine. I haven't had the *privilege* of using Windows 8 Hyper-V, but I manage a couple of Hyper-V servers. You can download the Windows 8 RSAT tools from Microsoft, which comes with the Hyper V management console. Once you have that installed point it to your localhost.

Now, make sure you *external network* is set to the proper network card of your hyper-v server. In my example my external network is connected to the gigabit ethernet nic of my physical machine. To get to this menu, right click on your hyper v server from the management console, and select 'Virtual Network Manager'.

[image]

After that, for your VM settings, select the same Network that you configured for external access in the previous step.

[image]

And last (or first?) make sure *That the physical computer has access to the network*.